# ibm Rational Clear case plugin(extension) is not working in Oracle Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle, clearcase, jdeveloper, clearcase-remote-client

Presently i am working with Oracle Jdeveloper 11g Release 1(11.1.1.6.0) as IDE and Rational clear case Remote client 7.1.2 for version control.
While installing the plug in for clear case there was only an option with clear case version 11.1.1.6.38.61.92 and i proceeded with the installation
but when i am trying to connect with clear case using the plugin i am getting an error message "*clear case executable is not installed ot not located in your system
environment path*".Is the plug in is **backward compatible**? please Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClearCase plugin would only work with a full ClearCase installation on your workstation (where JDeveloper is installed)

But I would be surprised if that plugin would work in a CCRC environment (where you don't have `cleartool` installed locally)

Comment: We are working with CCRC, the clear case server is installed in our client location.I am new to CCRC before i worked with SVN there we are directly connecting
to server remotely through the eclipse plugin is there any possibility in clear case similar to this?

Comment: Is the CCRC server installed where JDeveloper is installed?

Comment: Then a CCRC *server* should include cleartool: make sure it is in your path